# Audit tables not getting created/updated in hibernate envers

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am struggling since last week to configure hibernate envers 4.2 version in my existing project. However the _AUD, REV_INFO tables do not get updated. I also tried to hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto to be create so that they get generated dynamically but no luck.

As per new version I suppose I just need to add hibernate-envers jar in pom.xml and @Audited on entity class. 
I am referring to below 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html

for configuration. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: Do you have the same version of Envers as of Hibernate? Otherwise things should work fine. You can try setting a breakpoint on `EnversIntegrator` to see if it's being invoked on startup.

Comment: I made it working somehow but I am confused about hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto. I want  create my _AUD tables already and let hibernate update them. In that case what should I set in the flag?

Comment: If you want to update then you should use `update` :)